# Changing color of active col

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove the color of the column border after you have clicked on the image ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JknMP.png)). I have been looking through the whole code and been trying to change the colors but am not sure what to change in order to remove the border color. Please advise.

```css
   

 body{font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;overflow-x:hidden}

    #portfolio .portfolio-item{margin:0 0 15px;right:0}
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link{display:block;position:relative;max-width:400px;margin:0 auto}
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption{background:rgba(255,204,204,.7);position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0;transition:all ease .5s;-webkit-transition:all ease .5s;-moz-transition:all ease .5s}
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption:hover{opacity:1}
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content{position:absolute;width:100%;height:20px;font-size:20px;text-align:center;top:50%;margin-top:-12px;color:#FC9F9F}
    .btn-social,.scroll-top,.scroll-top .btn{width:50px;height:50px}
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content i{margin-top:-12px}
    #portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content h3,#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .caption .caption-content h4{margin:0}
    #portfolio *{z-index:2}
    @media (min-width:767px){#portfolio .portfolio-item{margin:0 0 30px}}
    .floating-label-form-group{position:relative;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:.5em;border-bottom:1px solid #eee}
    .floating-label-form-group input,.floating-label-form-group textarea{z-index:1;position:relative;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border:none;border-radius:0;font-size:1.5em;background:0 0;box-shadow:none!important;resize:none}.floating-label-form-group label{display:block;z-index:0;position:relative;top:2em;margin:0;font-size:.85em;line-height:1.764705882em;vertical-align:middle;vertical-align:baseline;opacity:0;-webkit-transition:top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;-moz-transition:top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;-ms-transition:top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease;transition:top .3s ease,opacity .3s ease}.
    floating-label-form-group:not(:first-child){padding-left:14px;border-left:1px solid #eee}
    .floating-label-form-group-with-value label{top:0;opacity:1}.floating-label-form-group-with-focus label{color:#FC9F9F}
    form .row:first-child .floating-label-form-group{border-top:1px solid #eee}

    .btn-outline{color:#FC9F9F;font-size:20px;border:2px solid #FC9F9F;background:0 0;transition:all .3s ease-in-out;margin-top:15px}
    .btn-outline.active,.btn-outline:active,.btn-outline:focus,.btn-outline:hover{color:#FC9F9F;background:#fff;border:2px solid #fff}
    .btn-primary.active,.btn-primary:active,.btn-success.active,.btn-success:active,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success{background-image:none}
    .btn-primary{color:#FC9F9F;background-color:#FC9F9F;border-color:#FC9F9F;font-weight:700}
    .btn-primary.active,.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary:focus,.btn-primary:hover,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary{color:#fff;background-color:#FC9F9F;border-color:#FC9F9F}
    .btn-primary.disabled,.btn-primary.disabled.active,.btn-primary.disabled:active,.btn-primary.disabled:focus,.btn-primary.disabled:hover,.btn-primary[disabled],.btn-primary[disabled].active,.btn-primary[disabled]:active,.btn-primary[disabled]:focus,.btn-primary[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:active,fieldset[disabled] 
    .btn-primary:focus,fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover{background-color:#FC9F9F;border-color:#FC9F9F}
    .btn-primary .badge{color:#FC9F9F;background-color:#FC9F9F}.btn-success{color:#FC9F9F;background-color:#FC9F9F;border-color:#FC9F9F;font-weight:700}
    .btn-success.active,.btn-success:active,.btn-success:focus,.btn-success:hover,.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success{color:#fff;background-color:#FC9F9F;border-color:#FC9F9F}
    .btn-success.disabled,.btn-success.disabled.active,.btn-success.disabled:active,.btn-success.disabled:focus,.btn-success.disabled:hover,.btn-success[disabled],.btn-success[disabled].active,.btn-success[disabled]:active,.btn-success[disabled]:focus,.btn-success[disabled]:hover,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success.active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:active,fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:focus,fieldset[disabled] 
    .btn-success:hover{background-color:#FC9F9F;border-color:#FC9F9F}.btn-success .badge{color:#FC9F9F;background-color:#fff}
    .btn-social{display:inline-block;border:2px solid #FC9F9F;border-radius:100%;text-align:center;font-size:20px;line-height:45px}
    .btn.active,.btn:active,.btn:focus{outline:0}.scroll-top{position:fixed;right:2%;bottom:2%;z-index:1049}
    .scroll-top .btn{font-size:20px;border-radius:100%;line-height:28px}.scroll-top .btn:focus{outline:0}
    .portfolio-modal .modal-content{border-radius:0;background-clip:border-box;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;border:none;min-height:100%;padding:100px 0;text-align:center}
    .portfolio-modal .modal-content h2{margin:0;font-size:3em}.portfolio-modal .modal-content img{margin-bottom:30px}.portfolio-modal .modal-content .item-details{margin:30px 0}
    .portfolio-modal .close-modal{position:absolute;width:75px;height:75px;background-color:transparent;top:25px;right:25px;cursor:pointer}
    .portfolio-modal .close-modal:hover{opacity:.3}
    .portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr{height:75px;width:1px;margin-left:35px;background-color:#FC9F9F;transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);z-index:1051}
    .portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr .rl{height:75px;width:1px;background-color:#FC9F9F;transform:rotate(90deg);-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);z-index:1052}
    .portfolio-modal .modal-backdrop{opacity:0;display:none}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>J</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/simplegrid.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Nunito+Sans|Playfair+Display|Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Navigation -->
    </head>
<body>
  <header>
     <div class="container navbar-container navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://"><img onload="this.style.opacity='1!important';" class= "logo" src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www.">TRAVEL</a></li>
           <li class="navbar-left active"><a href="http://www.> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
           <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://www.n"> INSPO </a></li>
           <li class="navbar-left"><a href="http://t"> ABOUT </a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </div>
</div>
  </header>

  <style>
      .row {
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 0px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #4a4a4a;
        }
         @media (min-width:468px) and (max-width:690px){
  .content {
     font-size: 14px;
      }
      </style>

    <!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
    <br>
    <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <hr class="star-primary">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/logos-set.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/logos-set.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/logos-set.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal4" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/logos-set.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal5" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                             
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/logos-set.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#portfolioModal6" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <div class="caption-content">
                        
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/logos-set.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      
          
    </section>
<!---End Contet-->


    <!-- Portfolio Modals -->


    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h4 style="  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #4a4a4a;">LOGOS</h4>
                            <hr class="star-primary">
                            <img src="img/logos.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                          
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Project Title</h2>
                            <hr class="star-primary">
                            <img src="img/portfolio/cake.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                            <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                                <li>Client:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Date:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Service:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Project Title</h2>
                            <hr class="star-primary">
                            <img src="img/portfolio/circus.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                            <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                                <li>Client:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Date:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Service:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Project Title</h2>
                            <hr class="star-primary">
                            <img src="img/portfolio/game.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                            <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                                <li>Client:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Date:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Service:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Project Title</h2>
                            <hr class="star-primary">
                            <img src="img/portfolio/safe.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                            <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                                <li>Client:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Date:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Service:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal6" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                <div class="lr">
                    <div class="rl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <h2>Project Title</h2>
                            <hr class="star-primary">
                            <img src="img/portfolio/submarine.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                            <p>Use this area of the page to describe your project. The icon above is part of a free icon set by <a href="https://sellfy.com/p/8Q9P/jV3VZ/">Flat Icons</a>. On their website, you can download their free set with 16 icons, or you can purchase the entire set with 146 icons for only $12!</p>
                            <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                                <li>Client:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Start Bootstrap</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Date:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">April 2014</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                                <li>Service:
                                    <strong><a href="http://startbootstrap.com">Web Development</a>
                                    </strong>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <span>Copyright &copy; 2017. . All rights reserved.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
<!---End Footer-->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/freelancer.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? It looks like you have set  `border: none;` on `.modal-content`. This removes the border completely.

Comment: There is a blue border showing after you have clicked on it.

Comment: You should remove the outline on the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `outline:none` on focus

```
.portfolio-link:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you :) ... please don't forget to accept the answer that works for you.

Comment: I did! I was also wondering if you would know how to change the style of the close button after you click on the image?

Comment: Yes, sure.. which style you want for that?

Comment: i would just like to remove the hover color and increase the size of the x.

Comment: for increase x size `.btn i{font-size: 21px; vertical-align: bottom;}`  and for remove hover color `.modal-body .btn-default:hover{background-color: #fff;  border-color: #ccc;}`

Comment: Ah thank you. I forgot to ask how to remove the current border color as well and is there a way to make the x thinner?

Comment: So there is a border currently around the close button.

Comment: Simple `.modal-body .btn-default{border:none}`